# Genyx Bootstrap Admin Pie Charts?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am currently using [this bootstrap admin theme](http://www.themes.suggelab.com/genyx/dashboard.html?user=suggeelson@suggeelson.com&password=somepassword) and I'm willing to recreate the piecharts in the charts category. Though I have absolultely no idea how the creator managed to create those. I guess he used flot which I'm already using but the result totally differs from what he did. Could someone help me with that ?

I would like to know if someone knows where to look in the sources of this template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, the code was actually simple to find, it's located in `js/pages/charts.js` and gives nice example of usage. My JS knowledge was just too low at the time I posted this question.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the code free now, template is no longer paid.
Download it from here - http://www.suggeelson.com/freebies/

Comment: Unrelated to the question, but really nice :)